# Why can't I get ALL Locust User Classes to spawn on each worker when using Distributed Mode?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, locust

Using:

- Locust 2.9.0
- Python 3.9.2
- distributed mode in docker:
- 2 workers
- 50 users

Each user type class is not spawning on every worker. I am getting 25 of QuickstartUser on one worker and 25 of AnotherQuickstartUser on another worker.
My issue with this is that one user type needs significantly more CPU.

Locustfile.py

```
import logging

from locust import HttpUser, task, between

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    @task
    def hello_world(self):
        logger.info(f"QUICKSTART_USER")


class AnotherQuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    @task
    def hello_world(self):
        logger.info(f"ANOTHER_QUICKSTART_USER")
```

I am expecting there to be an equal distribution of both user types across both workers.

Comment: Update locust, you are using a very old version.

Comment: @Cyberwiz thank you for reaching out so quickly. Unfortunately even on the latest version (worker log: `6f0022c0ead8/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.15.2.dev27`) I am still seeing the same issue.
(Possibly too much info...) I'm have been using 2.9 because it works well with a version of Pydantic I'm using. I'm not married to it in any way though. My main concern is the issue reported above.

Comment: If you can consistently reproduce this then maybe file a bug. Is the distribution always off in the same way? What if you ask for (for example) 9 users?

Comment: Yes, this is consistently reproducible. If I use your example of 9 users instead the master logs out `All users spawned: {"AnotherQuickstartUser": 5, "QuickstartUser": 4} (9 total users)`. With the users separated per worker. In this scenario, all 5 `AnotherQuickstartUser`'s were on Worker2. And 4 `QuickstartUser`'s spawned on Worker1. This is just generalized, but in real life one of my user classes uses significantly more cpu, so I'd like to try to have each user type on all workers.

Comment: Ok. There is a (working) unit test that test this functionality https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/3b73576e1731828d0113d656bafe91ba8787d5b3/locust/test/test_dispatch.py#L785 so its a bit strange. Maybe it only happens when there are only two classes?

Comment: Is it any different if the number of User classes is not the same as the number of workers?

Comment: Yes, it is a different outcome! That's very interesting. Sticking with the 50 users and 2 workers example, but this time I added an additional user class, and I saw the desired result of distributed users on each worker. I also get the desired result when using 50 users on 3 workers, and using the same 2 user classes as above.

Comment: I never really thought this was a bug, maybe just a configuration issue. Not really sure. Is this just a numbers game I need to play? My "real" locust setup is testing 8k users using 18 workers. With a `weight=1` for those "high cpu" users and `weight=5` for the "low cpu" users (1:5 ratio of users).

But that being said, maybe this isn't a bug but more a feature request? Do you think it would be a useful addition?